# How I read about Window communication Foundation (WCF)

Tags: wcf

Please any body tell me the link for WCF tutorial.

Comment: Check out: http://tinyurl.com/39jhwc2

Answer (score 1):

Hmm did you try googling a bit?:)

Anyway other than tons of great books and online references I guess you should start here,

[MSDN Getting Started Tutorial on WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)